# Inverting MOSFET drive circuit, is my scheme correct?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, switching, automotive, nmos

I am an automotive engineer student, building an inverting MOSFET driver  (where a MOSFET drives and controls another MOSFET, Vin low -> Main MOSFET closed, Vin high -> Main MOSFET open).

My application is to switch on and off the motor (supply by 12 V), and I am using 2 NMOS for this application.

[image: MOSFET Driver inverting circuit]

I made this circuit, with 2 power supplies, one for the Vin (to power the first MOSFET) and the other one for the motor. I tested the circuit but it's not working and the power supply which I used to switch on/off the first MOSFET will not allow me to control the voltage.

My question is, will adding a 10 k resistor in between the gate and the Vin solve the problem? And is anything missing or needs improvement from this scheme?

I appreciate all answers and help!

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmFEj.png]

Comment: Welcome! Please provide the exact schematic for your circuit. The one above has your 12 V supply floating and no connection to M1 gate. What is your end goal? To drive the motor?

Comment: Hi, my application is that the 12V supply would be used to drive the motor and open/close M2, the M1 gate would be drive by another power supply (either 0V or 5V) to open/close the gate. The M1 gate open -> M2 closed -> motor runs or M2 gate closed -> M2 open -> motor stop. My end goal is to switch on/off the motor based on the supply voltage of M1 (0 or 5V)

Comment: Please define what you mean by supply voltage of M1. Do you mean source voltage? Or do you have a signal source coming in from the left which isn't present in your schematic?

Comment: `... is my scheme correct?` No. The first thing I noticed is how the 12V source is connected (or left floating).

Comment: im sorry if I didn't explain my scheme good enough. But for the M1, the gate would be connected to another power supply (either 0V or 5V) to turn on/off the M1. And  the 12V source would be used to drive the motor and to turn on/off the M2. It would go from 12V supply -> Motor load -> switch ->nmos -> ground so it would be a closed loop

Comment: I updated the scheme so that it could be easier to understand

Comment: The schematic remains the same. Something missed in the edit?

Comment: Yes my scheme is 90% alike to the DC shunt motor drive. What value should I choose for the gate resistor as well as the pull down resistor, as I know the bigger the gate resistor value, the longer the switching time. The NMOS that im using is the IRF3205, which has 8mOhm Rds and I will applying 0/5V to the gate

Comment: Yes im sorry I forgot to press save update on the scheme, my scheme now is updated

Comment: For a low side NMOS drive of a high side motor, you normally don't need any inversion of the gate drive signal unless your PWM output is inverted. If it it, either change that to normal or add an inverter stage before the input.

Comment: D1 is going to prevent M2 from ever turning off.